# Is it possible to delete a HealthKit entry from my app?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm making an app with HealthKit and want to try to add a swipe to delete on my table view. I know there is a `healthStore.delete` option, but will this delete from the Health app and how would I know which `HKSample` to delete from HealthKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HKSample` class is an abstract class. Thus you should should never instantiate a `HKSample` object directly. Instead, you always work with one of the subclasses of `HKSample` (`HKCategorySample`, `HKQuantitySample`, `HKCorrelation`, or `HKWorkout` classes) where `HKSampleClass1` would be one of the subclasses.

```
healthStore.deleteObject(HKSampleClass1) { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in { 
    if success () {
      //success in deletion 
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first step, you need to define your specific key in HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier before you save your data to apple health.
And then, you can use HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier to delete specific health data.

```
let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()

// SAVE
var meta = [String: Any]()
meta[HKMetadataKeySyncVersion] = 1
meta[HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier] = "specific key"

let recordSample = HKQuantitySample(type: type, quantity: quantity, start: date, end: date, metadata: meta)
healthKitStore.save(bloodGlucoseSample) { success, error in
    if success {
        print("saving record to health success")
    } else {
        print("saving record to health error = \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}

// DELETE
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier, allowedValues: ["specific key"])
healthKitStore.deleteObjects(of: bloodGlucoseType, predicate: predicate) { success, _, error in
    if success {
       print("delete health record success")
    } else {
       print("delete health record error = \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling `healthStore.deleteObject()` will delete the sample from Health. However, keep in mind that your app may only delete samples that it saved to HealthKit.

You'll need to perform a query to retrieve the samples you want to show to the user. You could use `HKSampleQuery` or `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`.